# Why does this Ajax work in IE 7 and 8 but not FF or Chrome?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Say I'm using the following Ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml",  //test xml
        dataType: "xml", 
        success: xmlParser,
        error: alert("We can't find your XML!"),
        asynch: true
    });
});

function xmlParser(xml) {

    $(xml).find("CD:lt(3)").each(function () {

        $("#offers").append('<h1>' + $(this).find("ARTIST").text() + '</h1><p>' + $(this).find("YEAR").text() + '</p>');

    });
```

This works fine in IE 7 and 8, but doesn't work in FF or Chrome. I get an empty XML file and the following error in those browsers:

> XML Parsing Error: no element found
>   Location:
>   moz-nullprincipal:{77f5fd10-d793-4d35-9a4b-b8280b704fba}
>   Line Number 1, Column 1:

When I googled the error, I thought that it was due to the Ajax cross-domain issue. But if that were the case, wouldn't it be disabled in all browsers? Any help is appreciated - I'm kinda new to this whole Ajax thing.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that it is because of XSS, chrome + firefox are very strict about it, but i'm not sure if IE cares as much.

Comment: The "asynch" option on the $.ajax call needs to be spelled "async", but I doubt that is the cause of your problem.

Comment: try 
  var xmlParser = function (xml) {  instead, and place it before the ajax code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making an AJAX call from a client to an outside domain (unless you're writing code for www.w3schools.com.

This could be an SOP (Same Origin Policy) issue. You could try using JSONP (if their server is set up for that), or you can move that call to your server (PHP, C#, etc..) and have your server make the call on behalf of the client.

I suggest googling "SOP" and "JSONP".

Comment: That's what I thought it was at first, however, I am getting feedback from other users that if it were a cross-domain issue I would be getting the same result for all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     error: alert("We can't find your XML!"),
> ```

I wonder if you get the error because there actually is an error or because you misunderstand lambda expressions. The line I quoted will **always** popup an error message.

> ```
>     asynch: true
> ```

You also misspelled `async`. You really need to be more careful with what you type.

Comment: @cinqoTimo, that looks like a function call to me, not a function handle. In fact you will get the error *before your ajax call is even attempted*.